# Unable to run project on running emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

[image]

I'm able to run the emulator from the drop down menu, but despite the emulator running perfectly fine, I am unable to run the program on the emulator- the drop down menu still says <no device selected>

Thanks in advance

Comment: An emulator showing in list with connected devices in IDE?

Comment: yep the emulator is showing in the dropdown menu and I'm able to open the emulator. but even then when the emulator is running it still says <no devices selected>

Comment: Can you add `flutter doctor -v` output to the question?

Comment: just did that- the android sdk has a green tick but it says the 'Android license status is unknown'